# Are spurious TCP connections on port 53 a problem?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system

I run a server which amongst other things uses tinydns for DNS and axfrdns for handling transfer requests from our secondary DNS (another system).
I understand that tinydns uses port 53 on UDP and axfrdns uses port 53 on TCP.

I've configured axfrdns to only allow connections from my agreed secondary host.
I run logcheck to monitor my logs and every day I see spurious connections on port 53 (TCP) from seemingly random hosts.  They usually turn out to be from ADSL connections.

My question is; are these innocent requests or a security risk?
I am happy to block repeat offenders using iptables but don't want to block innocent users of one of the websites I host.

Thanks, Darren.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I assume you are using the server as an authoritive DNS server for a domain name. If that is the case any client that would need to resolve a name that your server has authority for would only need to use UDP. TCP is to be used for zone transfers.

And i also asume that you do not want the world to be able to do zone transfers. While not a security risk in itself zone transfers are usually only allowed to the secondary/backup dns servers. Most dns software also has ACL's to controll wich server is allowed to do zone transfers so you also have a second method of restricting that. But since i see security as allow only what is needed i suggest that you block tcp on port 53 for hosts that dont need to do zone transfers from you.

As a side note, tcp connections from random adsl hosts on tcp port 53 have malicious intent. This is because no legit client should need to do zone transfers from you. They might be trying to access confidential information related to your network, or to explit vulnerabilities to certain DNS software.

While that is not something to be paranoid about it is something that you should be aware of.

Comment: Thanks for this.
I will use iptables to lock it down to the hosts that act as secondaries (don't know why I didn't think of that before!).

Comment: @Darren - no, please don't.  Blocking DNS on tcp/53 breaks legitimate traffic.

Answer (score 10):

TCP is **not** only used for zone transfers.

TCP is the default fallback used by DNS clients should your DNS server ever send back a truncated (TC=1) UDP response.  This would happen if you are serving any data that exceeds 512 bytes in a single packet.

If you're running a DNS server then it *should* accept TCP connections from DNS clients, and there's no inherent security risk in doing so.  There's a very slight risk of DoS attacks against the DNS server, but that's true of any public facing service.

<strike>See [draft-ietf-dnsext-dns-tcp-requirements](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-dnsext-dns-tcp-requirements-03) which should be published as an RFC within the next month.</strike>

See [RFC 5966](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5966) for more details.

Ob disclaimer - I wrote that RFC.

Comment: As far as I know my DNS is not sending large packets - although I'd love to be able to test it to be sure.

The thing is, I've been DENYing these requests all along - with no known problems - all I'm proposing doing now is changing that DENY to an iptables rule that drops the packet.

Comment: there's no risk from these packets, but if you insist on not answering them you'll get less network load if you REJECT rather than DROP the inbound connections.

Comment: Now that's what I call an authoritative answer.

Answer (score 1):

The only things which should be using your host as a DNS server are

- localhost
- machines on your network that you set that host as the DNS server for

The simplest way to block "everything else" is to disable the service from listening on that address. If your own devices are outside "your network", use firewall rules (`iptables` or whatever) to only accept connections from your external network address(es). If they aren't fixed, you may need a VPN or other secure tunnel to bring the external hosts "inside your network".

Keep in mind that arbitrary DNS queries against your internal name server can potentially map out your entire network to an outside party and either present an attack vector or give away information that you'd rather not have the rest if the world having access to. "Random ADSL connection" could easily be zombie botnet machines being used to plan something nasty against you.

Comment: I already have dnscache listening on localhost only as a caching DNS server.
I have tinydns and axfrdns listening on the public interface as I publish DNS for the domains on that machine and I need to allow zone transfers.

Answer (score -4):

There are many security risks by opening incomming TCP to the nameserver - anyone who does not claim this are not sane. Just look at the root compromise history - Most of is done by using TCP in combination with UDP. The old MUST and SHOULD RFC was crafted by folks who know about security. If you have DNS zones not using the TC=1 bit (or exeeding 512 bytes) - Dont enable incomming TCP, let the morons do that in the future.

Comment: Huh?  Can you clarify what vulnerabilities you're talking about?